Serial Communication with Arduino Only Works When Minicom is Running on macOS
I am experiencing an issue with serial communication between my macOS system and an Arduino device. Both my Rust and Python scripts fail to send messages to the Arduino unless minicom is running. Here’s a detailed description of the problem:
Problem Summary

Environment: macOS (mac silicone M3 max), Arduino, Rust, Python
Serial Port: /dev/cu.usbmodem101
Baud Rate: 9600
Behavior:
When minicom is not running: Neither Rust nor Python scripts can successfully send messages to the Arduino. The arduino RX light will light up but the in-built LED flashes 3 times which is not the expected behaviour.
When minicom is running: Both Rust and Python scripts work correctly and can send messages to the Arduino with the expected outcome.
Even without the use of minicom, just sending the correct json from the SerialMonitor in Arduino IDE works perfectly.

The rust snippet from Tauri app.
// Prevents additional console window on Windows in release, DO NOT REMOVE!!
#![cfg_attr(not(debug_assertions), windows_subsystem = "windows")]
use serialport::SerialPort;
use std::time::Duration;
use serde::Serialize;
#[cfg(feature = "hardware-support")]
use std::fs::File;
#[tauri::command]
fn get_temperature() -> Result<f32, String> {
    #[cfg(feature = "hardware-support")]
    {
        // Path to the temperature sensor's device file
        let path = "/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-01191ee2142f/w1_slave"; // Replace '28-xxxx' with your sensor's ID
        let mut file = File::open(path).map_err(|e| e.to_string())?; // Convert the error to a String;

        let mut contents = String::new();
        file.read_to_string(&mut contents).map_err(|e| e.to_string())?;

        // The temperature data is usually at the end of the second line, after 't='
        let temp_str = contents.split_whitespace().last().unwrap().split("=").nth(1).unwrap();
        let temp_raw: i32 = temp_str.parse().unwrap();

        // Convert raw temperature to Celsius
        Ok(temp_raw as f32 / 1000.0)
    }

    #[cfg(not(feature = "hardware-support"))]
    {
        println!("Hardware support is not enabled. Temp running in stub mode.");
        Ok(69.69)
    }
}


#[derive(Serialize)]
struct BlinkData {
    blinks: u8,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct BlinkMessage {
    message_type: String,
    data: BlinkData,
}


#[tauri::command]
fn send_blink_message(port_name: &str, num_blinks: u8) -> Result<(), String> {
    // Open the serial port
    let mut port = serialport::new(port_name, 9600).open().expect("Failed to open port");

    // Create the JSON message
    let message = BlinkMessage {
        message_type: String::from("blink_led"),
        data: BlinkData { blinks: num_blinks },
    };

    // Serialize the message to JSON
    let json_message = match serde_json::to_string(&message) {
        Ok(json) => json,
        Err(e) => return Err(format!("Failed to serialize message: {}", e)),
    };

    // Send the JSON message over the serial port
    if let Err(e) = port.write_all(json_message.as_bytes()) {
        return Err(format!("Failed to write to port: {}", e));
    }

    // Print the JSON message to the console for debugging
    println!("JSON Message Sent: {}", json_message);

    // Add a newline to indicate the end of the message
    if let Err(e) = port.write_all(b"\n") {
        return Err(format!("Failed to write newline to port: {}", e));
    }

    Ok(())
}


fn main() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![get_temperature, send_blink_message])
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}


The Python example with lots of Serial specific settings.
import serial
import json
import time

def configure_serial_port(port_name):
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port=port_name,
        baudrate=9600,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        timeout=10,
        xonxoff=False,
        rtscts=False,
        dsrdtr=False
    )
    
    ser.dtr = False
    ser.rts = False
    ser.close()

def send_blink_message(port_name, num_blinks):
    try:
        # Configure the serial port settings
        configure_serial_port(port_name)

        # Open the serial port
        ser = serial.Serial(port_name, 9600, timeout=10)

        # Add a short delay to ensure the Arduino is ready to receive the message
        time.sleep(0.1)

        # Create the JSON message
        message = {
            "message_type": "blink_led",
            "data": {"blinks": num_blinks}
        }

        # Serialize the message to JSON
        json_message = json.dumps(message)

        # Print the JSON message for debugging
        print("JSON Message:", json_message)

        # Send the JSON message over the serial port
        print("Sending JSON message...")
        ser.write(json_message.encode('utf-8'))

        # Add a newline to indicate the end of the message
        print("Sending newline...")
        ser.write(b"\n")

        # Flush the port to ensure all data is sent
        print("Flushing port...")
        ser.flush()

        # Add a delay to ensure everything is sent before exiting the function
        time.sleep(0.1)

        print("Message sent to Arduino")

        ser.close()
        return True

    except serial.SerialException as e:
        print(f"Failed to open port: {e}")
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    port_name = "/dev/cu.usbmodem101"  # Change this to your port
    num_blinks = 3  # Set the number of blinks
    send_blink_message(port_name, num_blinks)

Here is the sketch
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

// Define the built-in LED pin
const int ledPin = LED_BUILTIN;

void setup() {
  // Initialize the built-in LED pin as an output
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  // Start the serial communication at 9600 baud rate
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // Check if there is any data available on the serial port
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // Read the incoming serial data
    String incomingMessage = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    
    // Parse the JSON message
    StaticJsonDocument<200> jsonDoc;
    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(jsonDoc, incomingMessage);
    
    // Check if parsing was successful
    if (!error) {
      // Extract the message type and blinks value
      const char* message_type = jsonDoc["message_type"];
      int blinks = jsonDoc["data"]["blinks"];
      
      // Check if the message type is 'blink_led'
      if (strcmp(message_type, "blink_led") == 0) {
        // Blink the LED the specified number of times
        for (int i = 0; i < blinks; i++) {
          digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); // Turn the LED on
          delay(500); // Wait for 500 milliseconds
          digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // Turn the LED off
          delay(500); // Wait for 500 milliseconds
        }
      }
    } else {
      // If parsing failed, print an error message
      Serial.println("Failed to parse JSONS");
    }
  }
}

Questions

Why do the scripts only work when minicom is running?
What specific configurations or states might minicom be setting that I need to replicate in my scripts?
How can I adjust my Rust and Python code to work without needing minicom running?

I have spent many hours, over many days with ChatGPT on this. Any insights or suggestions from a knowledgable human would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Your configure_serial_port function in python is probably not doing anything. You seem to be simply configuring it and closing it. You need to return the ser object you are configuring, even if you want to actually open it later in the code.

In general, having minicom open and bound to that serial port will definitely make your scripts not work. Two processes cannot simultaneously open the serial port. So there may be something else going on.

The issue was not waiting long enough for the Arduino to be ready to receive the serial data. Adding a 2 second delay between opening the serial port and sending the data resolved the issue. Presumably opening minicom first (which you can have running and still use the port), resolved the issue by getting the Arduino ready to receive the data. 2 seconds seems a long time though and it probably my next thing to tackle.
